# How to find out how the filesystem was created?

Tags: filesystems, partition

You can create the filesystem with `mkfs...` -- how to find out not only what filesystem is used on given partition, but what parameters where passed to `mkfs`?

So how to perform `mkfs` in reverse -- having prepared filesystem find out the call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the filesystem is ext2, ext3 or ext4, then you can use the command `tune2fs` to find out particulars about a given filesystem on a device.

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l <dev>
```

#### Example

```
$ sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda2
tune2fs 1.42.8 (20-Jun-2013)
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          /boot
Filesystem UUID:          xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    user_xattr acl
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              128016
Block count:              512000
Reserved block count:     25600
Free blocks:              355130
Free inodes:              127934
First block:              1
Block size:               1024
Fragment size:            1024
Reserved GDT blocks:      256
Blocks per group:         8192
Fragments per group:      8192
Inodes per group:         2032
Inode blocks per group:   254
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Tue Jul 15 21:26:21 2014
Last mount time:          Fri Sep  5 08:17:04 2014
Last write time:          Fri Sep  5 08:17:04 2014
Mount count:              38
Maximum mount count:      -1
Last checked:             Tue Jul 15 21:26:21 2014
Check interval:           0 (<none>)
Lifetime writes:          172 MB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           128
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Journal backup:           inode blocks
```

The parameter "Filesystem Features" lists what you're asking for.

#### What devices do I have?

You can use the command `lsblk` to list these out.

85.9G  0   lvm

```
$ lsblk | head -8 | column -t
NAME           MAJ:MIN  RM  SIZE    RO  TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0      0   238.5G  0   disk
├─sda1         8:1      0   200M    0   part  /boot/efi
├─sda2         8:2      0   500M    0   part  /boot
└─sda3         8:3      0   237.8G  0   part
├─fedora-root  253:0    0   50G     0   lvm   /
├─fedora-swap  253:1    0   2G      0   lvm   [SWAP]
└─fedora-home  253:2    0   185.9G  0   lvm
```

Comment: Thank you very much, entire table is actually very helpful when recreating `mkfs` (like block size).